# Issues with submit button

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any difference between these two ways:

1)
`<form name=form>
<input type=submit >
</form>`

2)
`document.form.submit();`

Does it send any interrupts by clicking on submit button or by javascript.
Kindly let me know the major differences between these two ways of submit

Comment: With the second approach you might reduce the number of users of your web site since clients must have JavaScript enabled :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you submit with a submit button it will send the name of the submit button to the server, it can't happen if you submit with javascript.

Besides of this, I don't think there is a difference.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this Info... :)
I was looking for this ind of answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

The first line permits to declare the html form with a submit button :

```
//Submit form when the submit button has been clicked
<form id="myForm" action='myPage.php'><input type="submit" value"submit my form"></form>
```

And the second one is the JS way to submit the above form :

```
//JS way to submit the form
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml